# I can't change initial Xcode storyboard view

Tags: xcode4, storyboard

I'm trying to change my initial view in my storyboard, but, when I change it I get this strange view:

[image: strange initial view]

Anyone can tell me why?

Ps: In my project I don't have any tab controllers, so I don't know why there is a tab over there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you are doing a universal app and are looking at the wrong View? 
What you have there is a navigation bar in a blank view and probably a message in your messages telling you that you have not got a root view controller.

In the past I have solved this by

a) Restarting XCode.

b) Making a new view, copying and pasting the essential View Controller from my old View and deleting the old View.

c) Checking in my summary that the view I think is being talked to actually is the one specified.

d) Looking at my storyboard and checking that the viewcontroller is specified in the object inspector as "Is initial View Controller" by checking the box.

Comment: I had the same issue where I created a new version of a view but had to delete the old one before it would let me specify the custom class. Xcode is the buggiest Apple product, ironically.